# Examples of coexact sequences of groups which are not exact

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, exact-sequence

Say a sequence $A\overset{f}{\to}B\overset{g}{\to}C$ of group morphisms is *coexact* if $\operatorname{Coker}f= \operatorname{Im}g$.

The first isomorphism theorem ensures that exactness implies coexactness. In an abelian category they coincide (because the property of being abelian is autodual). Where do they differ?

**Question.** What are some examples of coexact sequences of groups morphisms which are not exact?

I think we want the normal closure of $\operatorname{Im}(f)\leq B$ to be strictly smaller than $\operatorname{Ker}g$, but I'm really bad with all this normal stuff.

Comment: I'm not sure how to interpret $\operatorname{Coker}f= \operatorname{Im}g$ other than the fact that $g$ factors through $\operatorname{Coker}f$ and gives an isomorphism with the image, which is just a reformulation of exactness.

Comment: @CaptainLama: But if the image of $f$ is not normal, the cokernel of $f$ is not just the quotient by the image of $f$!

Comment: @EricWofsey Of course, silly me...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $A$ be a non-normal subgroup of $B$ and let $N$ be the normal subgroup it generates.  Then the sequence $A\to B\to B/N$ is coexact: the cokernel of $A\to B$ is the universal morphism out of $B$ that annihilates $A$, which is just the quotient $B\to B/N$.

More generally, coexactness of $A\overset{f}{\to}B\overset{g}{\to}C$ means precisely that the image of $f$ generates the kernel of $g$ as a normal subgroup, since the cokernel of $f$ is exactly the quotient by normal subgroup generated by its image.

Comment: Dear Eric, this is what I meant in the last sentence of my question. What I tried to ask for is an explicit example :)

Comment: @Arrow As an explicit example you can take $B = D_8$ = dihedral group of order eight which has the presentation $\langle x,a \mid a^4 = x^2 = e, xax^{-1} = a^{-1} \rangle$. Then the subgroup $\{e, x \}$ of order $2$ is non-normal. Its normal closure is $\{ e,x,a^2,a^2x \}$.  See https://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Dihedral_group:D8.